# swift - performSegue not working in RxSwift Observable subscribe

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have the following code:

```
loginViewModel.facebookLogin
.asObservable()
subscribe() { [unowned self] facebookLogin in
     if let isLoggedIn = facebookLogin.element?.isLoggedIn {
         if isLoggedIn {
              elf.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toRestaurantSelect", sender: self)
              }
      }

     if let didLoginFail = facebookLogin.element?.didLoginFail {
         self.errorLabel.isHidden = !didLoginFail
     }
  }
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The facebookLogin is a Variable and is updated when the user logs in. However, the performSegue is not called (the condition is true). Strangely enough, if I turn on Slow animations in the emulator the segue is executed. When Slow animations are turned off the segue doesn't execute (the Facebook login works). Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should use the main thread to make it work

```
    loginViewModel.facebookLogin
        .asObservable()
        .subscribe() { [unowned self] facebookLogin in
            if let isLoggedIn = facebookLogin.element?.isLoggedIn {
                if isLoggedIn {


                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toRestaurantSelect", sender: self)

                    }



                }
            }

            if let didLoginFail = facebookLogin.element?.didLoginFail {
                self.errorLabel.isHidden = !didLoginFail
            }
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the observation with the main scheduler:

```
loginViewModel.facebookLogin
.asObservable()

// Switch to the main scheduler
.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)


subscribe() { [unowned self] facebookLogin in
     if let isLoggedIn = facebookLogin.element?.isLoggedIn {
         if isLoggedIn {
              elf.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toRestaurantSelect", sender: self)
              }
      }

     if let didLoginFail = facebookLogin.element?.didLoginFail {
         self.errorLabel.isHidden = !didLoginFail
     }
  }
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```